# it's posible to animate DataGrid column collapsing in Silverlight/WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid, visualstatemanager

I have a simple `DataGrid` in Silverlight with this columns templates:

```
<data:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...>

    <data:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idCol" Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" />

    <data:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameCol" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />

    <data:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="descriptionCol" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />

</data:DataGrid
```

and I want to collapse and expand some columns in a animated way.  Is that possible? Because I can't use VSM on column width templates and column width is not a DP, it's a `DataGridLength`.

```
private void ExpandColumns()
{
    // not animated expanding
    //myDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    //myDataGrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;.

}

private void CollapseColumns()
{
    // not animated collapsing
    //myDataGrid.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    //myDataGrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be a bit of a hack, but how about animating `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` on the column?  Basically set them according to what you want to do and animate `MinWidth` to a higher value for expanding, and animate `MaxWidth` to a lower value for collapsing.

Here's the complete xaml for animating on MinWidth (I still believe this is somewhat hackish):

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="SolveProblems.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridColumn.MinWidth)" Storyboard.TargetName="dataGridCheckBoxColumn">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="80"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridColumn.MinWidth)" Storyboard.TargetName="dataGridCheckBoxColumn1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="100,54,129.5,82.5">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dataGridCheckBoxColumn" Width="{Binding Columns[0].MinWidth, ElementName=dataGrid, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dataGridCheckBoxColumn1" Width="{Binding Columns[1].MinWidth, ElementName=dataGrid, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,115,22,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: I was able to get them to animate.  See this code: `<Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
   <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridColumn.MinWidth)" Storyboard.TargetName="dataGridTextColumn">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="150"/>
   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>`

Comment: Just to add on... I wasnt able to get the `Width` property to animate in xaml (I'm using blend).  But I do see `DataGridColumn.WidthProperty`, `DataGridColumn.MinWidthProperty', `DataGridColumn.MaxWidthProperty' as a Dependency Properties.  And you're right... I'm not sure how to animate a DataGridLength, but `inWidth` and `MaxWidth` are just doubles :)

Comment: hmm... are you sure you can animate the MinWidth and MaxWidth? i think they have to be dependency properties to be able to animate...

Comment: The example I gave in my first comment worked fine in xaml... I didnt do it in code behind though.

Comment: Oops, sorry I did mean xaml code. But now I know why... You are using WPF and I was talking about Silverlight! :) Anyway, +1 as in WPF this will work! Another potential solution I think is to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead then you can animate the control inside the `DataTemplate` without animating the actual column.

Comment: Ahhhh yes :)  that would be a difference.  And yes, `MinWidth` and `MaxWidth` are not DPs in Silverlight.  The `DataGridTemplateColumn` sounds like a good solution to me.